# ionic - use [hidden] to hide items that not contains string

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a variable that holds a textfield value

```
 this.search_value = null;
```

Than have a list with cards:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of lotes" class="card">

   <div [hidden]="(this.search_value && this.search_value.trim()) || i.nome_lote.includes(this.search_value) ">
   ...
   </div>

</div
```

As you can see, I'm trying to hide the cards that not contains the `this.search_value` string in their `i.nome_lote` value.

As I type in the search field, the variable `search_value` is being updated correctly.

Otherwise, it is hiding nothing or everything at once... It's not considering the string contains condition.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this the best way to reach that?

Comment: What is the purpose of having ```this.search_value.trim()``` as a condition? It's always going to be false.

Comment: @nullptr.t just check if the value isn't null

Comment: I'm trying something like: `this.search_value && i.nome_lote.includes(this.search_value)` I mean: when the `search_value` isn't empty and it is present in `i.nome_lote`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is not correct. You are using `or` operator, so when `search_value` has a value all will be hidden, the second condition won't be even evaluated. You need to use `and` operator, i.e `&&`, also you need to check that `i.nome_lote.includes(search_value)` is **not** truthy, since it will be otherwise hidden if condition is `true`. So change your code to:

```html
<div [hidden]="search_value && !i.nome_lote.includes(search_value)">
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzjmv2?file=src/app/app.component.html)**